# What do we do when an existing tag name can also mean something new?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [GNU Scientific Library (GSL)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) has been around for a long time. 
It has the tag name [gsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsl).

In 2015, the C++ community released a support library.  
It's called the [Guidelines Support Library (GSL)](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

What do we do in situations like this when both deserve a tag? 
 Should I seek to change the existing [gsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsl) to something more descriptive?

Should existing and already used tag names remain the same, while new tags must accommodate for the already taken names?

Comment: You should probably answer this question as opposed to leaving it as an edit.  That way, it can be found as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tags for both libraries already exist.
It turns out that the Guidelines Library can be discussed using [cpp-core-guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpp-core-guidelines).
In this case, the library is a supplement to the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines).

Comment: This doesn't answer the general question in the title, however. I would think that in that case, you'd want to leave the existing tag name, especially if there are a lot of questions tagged with it.